# At which pixel do I draw these frequencies lines?

Tags: c++, math, frequency

I need to plot on a C++ GUI Display some "lines" that identify frequency "bands". Such as these:

[image]

Since my working frequency range will be between 20 hz and 20 khz, frequency is logaritmic and my C++ Display width is 270 pixels, at which pixel should I draw 100hz, 1 khz and 10 khz lines?

I can't get the math scaling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from MBo

```
0   = a + b * Log(20)
270 = a + b * Log(20000)
```

Subtract

```
270 = b * (Log(20000) - Log(20))
270 = b * Log(20000/20)
270 = b * Log(1000)
b = 270 / Log(1000)
```

If you are using log base 10 Log(1000) = 3 so b = 270/3 = 90.

Substituting in the first

```
0 = a + 270 * Log(20) / Log(1000)
a = - 270 * Log(20) / Log(1000)
```

Again with log base 10

```
a = - 90 * Log(20) = -117
```

So using Log base 10 you would draw lines at

```
x_100   = -90 * Log(20) + 90 * Log(100)    = -117 + 180 =  63
x_1000  = -90 * Log(20) + 90 * Log(1000)   = -117 + 270 = 153
x_10000 = -90 * Log(20) + 90 * Log(10000)  = -117 + 360 = 243
```

Using your formula

```
double OldMin = log(20); 
double OldMax = log(20000); 
double NewMin = 0.0; 
double NewMax = 270.0; 
double OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin); 
double NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin); 
double OldValue = log(1000);

double NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin;
```

It looks like the same results.

Comment: what's different if I use this formula instead? `double NewValue = (((OldValue - OldMin) * NewRange) / OldRange) + NewMin;`

Comment: With `double OldMin = log(20); double OldMax = log(20000); double NewMin = 0.0; double NewMax = 270.0; double OldRange = (OldMax - OldMin);  double NewRange = (NewMax - NewMin); double OldValue = log(1000);` for example...

Comment: It looks like it is an equivalent formula.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find coefficients `a` and `b` of equation

```
 x = a + b * Log(f)
```

for two border cases `f=20, x=0` and `f=20000, x=269`

Comment: Uhm, what do you mean with "a" and "b"? I just need x-axis position. Let say I want to find pixel for the 100hz freq :O I need only one value! Sorry maybe I'm so stupid eheh

Comment: when you find a and b, you  will know formula to transform frequency f to position x